# Facebook javascript sdk return wrong user id

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get user information..and I'm using this method

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

but the problem is that the response contains a wrong user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using Login 2.0 respectively the new JS SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0) and are getting an app-invidual `user_id` as described in the Graph API v2.0 Upgrading Guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I can't understand how get list of user's friends

Comment: /me/friends now don't not work. How get friends with new version api?

Comment: Sorry, but your question says nothing about friends... Read the links I provided, it's all in there.